# Iterating two lists with two different sliding windows in one loop

Tags: python

I have two very large lists, and I want use one loop for iterating over two of them with the different sliding windows. Is that possible? if not, what is the best way?

> For example,
> I have A and B, I want a loop which provide the summation of sliding window 2 of list B and sliding window of size 3 of
> A.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
B = [-1,2, 3, 14, 51, 16, 7, 18 ]
```

Sliding window of size 3 in `A = [1,4,7,10]`
Sliding window of size 2 in `B = [-1,3,5,7]`
Out: `A + B = [0, 7, 12, 17]`

Comment: Have you tried zip? `[i+j for i, j in zip(A[::3], B[::2])]`. This should work as long as the number of element in the operation (summation) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as a map over slices as follows:

```
from operator import add
res = map(add, A[::3], B[::2])
```

Another option is with a list comprehension / generator expression:

```
res = [a + b for a, b in zip(A[::3], B[::2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with this way: for those, who maybe have same problem in future:

```
w1 = 3
w2 = 2
t = []
for i in range(0, 12, w1):
    index_w = int(i/w1)
    sum_temp = A[i]+ B[w2*index_w]
    t.append(sum_temp)
```